# How to search for vue components with vim's gf?

Tags: vimscript, navigation, include

I want to go to a vue component file.

Vue component filenames are written in PascalCase: `ExampleComponent.vue`

In html (or in my case `blade.php`) the `ExampleComponent.vue` is instantiated
by `<example-component>` (kebab-case).
When my cursor is over `<example-component>` I get `E447: Can't find file "container-gallery" in path`

In the docs is written:

```
If the file can't be found, 'includeexpr' is used to
modify the name and another attempt is done.
```

So my Question is how do I use `includeexpr` in order to change from

```
example-component
```

to

```
resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue
```

Further research pointed me to the substitute function:
`:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname, ..... )`

but then I would need to preprocess the `v:fname` variable.
A hint how to tackle that problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem gets simpler if `path` includes `resources/js/components` and `suffixesadd` includes `.vue`; then `includeexpr` only has to change `example-component` to `ExampleComponent`. This might be doable as a simple substitute; if not, you might be able to grab some code from tpope/abolish (the coercion mappings do similar transformations)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I set the right `path` and the `suffixesadd` and it works for `ExampleComponent`. Now in order to transform kebab-case to PascalCase I used regex. `echo substitute('kebab-case','\(\w\+\)\(\-\)\(\w\+\)','\u\1\u\3','')` prints KebabCase. But `setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\(\w\+\)\(\-\)\(\w\+\)','\u\1\u\3','')` does not work. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the `substitute` function in a own function:

```
function! B(name)
   return substitute(a:name,'\(\w\+\)\(\-\)\(\w\+\)','\u\1\u\3','')
endfunction`
```

> ~~/.vim/bundle/vim-blade/ftplugin/blade.vim --->this plugin overwrites my `setlocal path` so for a quick fix I added my changes to that plugin:

```
11 setlocal suffixesadd=.blade.php,.php,.vue
12 " setlocal includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\.','/','g')
13 setlocal includeexpr=B(v:fname)
14 setlocal path+=resources/views;
15 setlocal path+=resources/js/components/;
16 setlocal path+=resources/js/components/gallery;
```

Instead of calling directly the substitution function I call my function B.
I have no idea why I had to wrap `substition` in a custom function.
It's not perfect, but now it changes from kebab-case to PascalCase and finds my vue-files. Suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Comment: Notes: use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/blade.vim` and you’re able to override all previous ftplugins where you want to. As for setting indentexpr, try your original and then run `setlocal indentexpr?`, I bet there’s an issue with escaping. One solution is to use `let l:&indentexpr` which assigns the option to a string; no escaping for set necessary.